# How to pronounce CRUD?

Tags: communication

I was talking to a co-worker and was talking of how Database operations usually can be broken down into one of the elements of CRUD- Create, read, update and delete.

That's when I realised that I do not know how to pronounce CRUD.

So is there a definite, well accepted way to pronounce CRUD?

Comment: CHROOD ? How else ?

Comment: How to prononce could be a very hard topic here. Remeber that we all are writing, and you'll find no direct link between the way english is written and the way you should prononce it.

Comment: @deadalnix: I know that very often pronunciation is a regional thing, but what i want to know is whether there is a definite pronunciation. (eg C# is C sharp and nor C Pound or C hash)

Comment: Wait C# isn't C Pound?

Comment: Please read this meta question - http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/we-cant-pronounce-anything - I'm not sure your question is constructive enough.

Answer (score 20):

I pronounce it like I pronounce the word meaning miscellaneous and unidentified matter, "Crud". The IPA version is /kɹʌd/.

Comment: Miscellaneous and unidentified matter? I though it meant [something of poor quality](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crud#Noun) - which to me was always right to the point with CRUD :)

Comment: @YannisRizos Something of poor quality is another word that starts with "cr"

Comment: crap is a synonym of crud, and it may even refer to CRUD as an acronym for create, retrieve, alter, purge.

Comment: +1. According to the [German wiki entry](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) it's the correct translation (given that `ɹ` doesn't exist in German, I think it's safe to say it's the English pronunciation).

Answer (score 16):

Erm - exactly as you would think... like "MUD" but with a "CR" on the front ?

Answer (score 6):

Like Crush but with a D at the end:)

Answer (score 3):

k as in kilo, r as in romeo, u pronounced as u in mud, d as in delta.

I hope this give you some idea. :-)

Answer (score 3):

K -RUD

Its actually a term I don't use as in Belfast CRUD is slang from rubbish.

Comment: I think that's the case all over the UK (certainly here in south east England) - it's often written but not commonly spoken here :)